# nextProps in componentWillReceiveProps() does not get the right value for state array prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have spent quite a time to read and try to make work for the data that I am trying to pass through.
The issue is that the state variable is an array type, when I do setState on same,  componentWillReceiveProps does not have the right value for nextProps.

## Following is the code snippet

This will render with Search component

```
 var readOnlyTokens = ['ConnectionStatus = Down, Up'];

 this.render = function () {
        var self = this;

         class SearchApp extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    value: [], // Issue with this variable
                    action: undefined
                };
                this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
                self.readonlySearchStatesAppInstance = this;
            }

            handleClick(e, value) {
                console.log(value);
            }

            render() {
                return (
                    <Search
                        id="readonly_modifyStates"
                        readOnly={true}
                        // value={readOnlyTokens.concat([])}
                        value={readOnlyTokens}
                        logicMenu={['OR']}
                        action={this.state.action}
                    />
                );
            }
    };
    this.addReadOnlyTokens = function (tokens) {
        // Value of tokens as ['Managed Status = InSync, OutSync']
        this.readonlySearchStatesAppInstance.setState({value: tokens, action:"add"});          
    };
```

Search Component

```
  class Search extends React.Component {

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // Issue here is nextProps.value is still having the initial render value ['ConnectionStatus = Down, Up'] instead of ['Managed Status = InSync, OutSync']

        switch(nextProps.action){
            case "add":
                this.searchWidget.addTokens(nextProps.value);
                break;
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="search-component"
                 ref={el => this.el = el}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

After reading at different answers, I have tried array.concat also - but for vain.

Any help is much appreciated..
Thanks

Comment: where are you changing value of `readOnlyTokens` ?

Comment: As Vivek just asked - it does not appear you are modifying readOnlyTokens (which, by the way, would be an odd name if you are modifying it...)

Comment: Thanks @Vivek and Chris - for pointing it out. I was in the impression that in setState the value:tokens should take whatever I want to send. Modified the code to take the readOnlyToken (agreed odd name ;)) variable & it worked. so modified version is -   ==========                                                     
 this.addReadOnlyTokens = function (tokens) {
        // Value of tokens as ['Managed Status = InSync, OutSync'] 
       readOnlyTokens = tokens;
        this.readonlySearchStatesAppInstance.setState({value: readOnlyTokens, action:"add"});          
    };